# three.js and infinite forward grid movement

Tags: javascript, three.js

[Retrowave Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcboN.png)

I have been trying to get the blue grid in three.js to move infinitely forward like you are moving toward the sun.  I haven't seen any examples on how to do this.  Something similar to this effect: http://www.motoko.tv/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Motoko-Showreel-Loop-12.5fps.gif

I have tried this:

```
   lines1.position.z = Math.cos( time ) * 0.75 + 1.25;
```

This is the grid. I used THREE.Line:

```
for (var i = -size; i <= size; i+=steps)
{
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-size, - 0.10,i));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(size, -0.10,i));

    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, - 0.10,-size));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, - 0.10,size));
}

var lines1 = new THREE.Line(geometry, material, THREE.LineSegments)


scene.add(lines1);
```

Comment: Use `position.z = time % something` to loop the movement

Comment: It does not even move at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

From the scratch, I came up with the approach of using `THREE.GridHelper()` with `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 50);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var division = 20;
var limit = 100;
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(limit * 2, division, "blue", "blue");

var moveable = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= division; i++) {
  moveable.push(1, 1, 0, 0); // move horizontal lines only (1 - point is moveable)
}
grid.geometry.addAttribute('moveable', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint8Array(moveable), 1));
grid.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    time: {
      value: 0
    },
    limits: {
      value: new THREE.Vector2(-limit, limit)
    },
    speed: {
      value: 5
    }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    uniform float time;
    uniform vec2 limits;
    uniform float speed;
    
    attribute float moveable;
    
    varying vec3 vColor;
  
    void main() {
      vColor = color;
      float limLen = limits.y - limits.x;
      vec3 pos = position;
      if (floor(moveable + 0.5) > 0.5){ // if a point has "moveable" attribute = 1 
        float dist = speed * time;
        float currPos = mod((pos.z + dist) - limits.x, limLen) + limits.x;
        pos.z = currPos;
      } 
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos,1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    varying vec3 vColor;
  
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);
    }
  `,
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});

scene.add(grid);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  grid.material.uniforms.time.value = time;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Alex Any link to a live example of how you implement this code? [Reference](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/moving-retrowave-grid/3506?u=prisoner849)

Comment: I got it to work thank you so much.  I have never seen this before:  vertexShader: ` What's   `

Comment: @Alex You're welcome :) Modern browsers support multi-line strings, when uses ` ... `

Comment: I have one last question.. How did you discover how to do this?  I don't see any documentation on something of this sort.  Could you send me a link to it?  Thanks again

Comment: @Alex Tough question :) I've just looked into the source code of the grid helper, saw how its vertices organized, had a thought that they can be animated with shaders :)

Comment: Are there any examples out there similar with what you did?  I would like to apply this to other elements as well =). Thank you so much again

Comment: Great code! How would you approach adding glow effect on the lines @prisoner849 ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to use textures, search voor: three js moving texture.
Check out this example: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

This way you don't have to work with a lot of vertices and controlling them.

Regards,

Gerdon